# Acessando linha da matriz e troca linha por coluna

Tags: c, matriz

Boa tarde amigos, eu estou tentando fazer uma troca em uma matriz, trocar os valores da primeira linha com os valores da última coluna. Sei que uma linha de uma matriz em C é um vetor. Pensei em fazer assim mas como sempre minha lógica está errada.

```
#define TAMANHO 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void receberMatriz(int matrizPRI[TAMANHO][TAMANHO]);
void ordenarMatriz(int matrizPRI[TAMANHO][TAMANHO]);


    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        int matrizPRI[TAMANHO][TAMANHO];



        receberMatriz(matrizPRI);
        ordenarMatriz(matrizPRI);

        return 0;

    }






void receberMatriz(int matrizPRI[TAMANHO][TAMANHO])
{
    int lin, col;

    for(lin = 0; lin < TAMANHO; lin++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < TAMANHO; col++)
        {
            printf("Matriz Principal [%i][%i]: ", lin, col);
            scanf("%i", &matrizPRI[lin][col]);
        }
    }
}

void ordenarMatriz(int matrizPRI[TAMANHO][TAMANHO])
{
    int lin, col;
    int AUX1[TAMANHO], AUX2[TAMANHO];

    for(lin = 0; lin < TAMANHO; lin++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col == TAMANHO; col++)
        {
            if(matrizPRI[lin] == 1)
            {
                AUX1[col] = matrizPRI[col];
                AUX1[col]+1;
            }
            else if(matrizPRI[col] == 4)
            {
                AUX2[col] = matrizPRI[col];
                AUX2[col]+1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(lin = 0; lin < TAMANHO; lin++)            
    {
        for(col = 0; col < TAMANHO; col++)
        {
            if(matrizPRI[lin] == 1)
            {
                matrizPRI[lin] = AUX2[col];
            }
            else if(matrizPRI[col == 4])
            {
                matrizPRI[col] == AUX1[lin];
            }
        }
    }

    for(lin = 0; lin < TAMANHO; lin++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < TAMANHO; col++)
        {
            printf("[%i] "), matrizPRI[lin][col];
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Como posso fazer troca de uma linha de uma matriz com uma coluna? A troca seria feita de uma única linha e uma única coluna, sendo assim acredito que não de para usar bubble sort. Alguém da uma luz pra clarear essa mente...

Comment: o que trocar os valores da primeira linha com os valores da última coluna tem a ver com bubble sort? Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Pode fornecer um exemplo de matriz de entrada e o resultado esperado para essa matriz?

Comment: Realmente vou tentar reformular a pergunta, estava meio de cabeça quente por não estar achando a lógica. Vou colocar o enunciado da questão:

Construa um algoritmo para ler uma matriz 4 x 4 e troque os valores da 1ª linha pelos da 4ª coluna, vice-e-versa. Escrever ao final a matriz obtida.

Comment: Você pode fazer algo recursivo, assim, tendo controle de cada elemento da linha e coluna para poder troca-los de forma segura. A recursividade para quando não puder encontrar o próximo elemento da linha/coluna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi do problema a resposta é bem simples e não precisa do algoritmo do buble sort.

```
#define TAMANHO 4
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int matriz[TAMANHO][TAMANHO];

int i, j, aux;

//recebe os valores dos elementos da matriz
for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < TAMANHO; j++){
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

//faz a troca
for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++){
    aux = matriz[0][i];
    matriz[0][i] = matriz[TAMANHO - i -1][TAMANHO - 1];
    matriz[TAMANHO - i -1][TAMANHO - 1] = aux;

}

//exibe a matriz após a troca
for(i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < TAMANHO; j++){

        printf("%d", matriz[i][j]);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```